# is there a difference between "to buy" and "to buy up"

Tags: difference

I was wondering if there is a difference in the meaning of these two sentences.

> They bought up pieces of old furniture and passed them off as antiques. (This is a dictionary example.)

> They bought pieces of old furniture and passed them off as antiques.

If there is no difference, why do we put *up* after the verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of phrasal verbs formed with "up":

> eat up, give up, look up...

They often have meanings related to "do something and achieve a result", but each one has a specfic meaning that must be learnt.  You can't guess the exact meaning from the words.

So "eat up" means "eat and finish eating everything on the plate".  "Look up" means "look for a word and find it in a dictionary".

"Buy up" suggests "buy all, or a lot of" something.  So "They bought up pieces of furniture" suggests that they bought all, or a lot of furniture.